# Extract table data in a BLOB field

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql

I am trying to extract data from tables in a delimiter separated value format. To extract data i am concatenating all the columns of the table with each other and then converting the concatenated record into binary and  storing into a table. Below is the code that i am using

```
DECLARE
l_temp_blob blob;
begin
dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_temp_blob, TRUE);
For src in (select A||'~'||B||'~'||C||..........||'`'||Z AS DAT FROM <TABLE>)
LOOP
dbms_lob.append(l_temp_blob,utl_raw.cast_to_raw(src.DAT||chr(10)));
END LOOP;
insert into temp_table('FIle',l_temp_blob);
COMMIT;
END;
```

I am facing severe performance issue in this, a table with 88k records is getting extracted in 8 hours. My tables have CLOB columns in them along with VARCHAR2 and NUMBER columns.

Is there a better way to do this. Since we don't have direct access to server where database is installed we cannot use Oracle Export utility and Data Pump utility.

Comment: If you want a CSV export, then there are a gazillion client tools that can do that. It's even possible with `sqlplus`

Comment: There is a limitation of using PLSQL only. Also if you can share how to do it with sqlplus for tables with CLOB columns that would be really helpful.

Comment: CSV is the wrong file format when dealing with CLOB data...or any data that could contain the "end of line" delimiter